# How to set property of radio button to checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are two radio buttons in my code:

```
<input type="radio" id='production' ng-click="division($event)" ng-model="formData.division" value="Production">
  <label for="production">Production</label>

<input type="radio" id='operation' ng-click="division($event)" ng-model="formData.division" value="Operations">
  <label for="operation">Operations</label>
```

And there are more radio buttons after:

```
<div class="prod">
  <h2>Production</h2>
    <label><b>Project Captain: <small id="small">*</small></b></label>
    <input type="radio" class="projCap" ng-model="formData.projCap" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" class="projCap" ng-model="formData.projCap" value="no">No

    <label><b>Supervisor: <small id="small">*</small></b></label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.supervisor" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.supervisor" value="no">No<br><br>
</div>

<div class="op">
  <h2>Operations</h2>
    <label><b>Manager: <small id="small">*</small></b></label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.mngr" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.mngr" value="no">No   

    <label><b>Assistant Manager: <small id="small">*</small></b></label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.asMngr" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.asMngr" value="no">No  <br><br>
</div>
```

I want to save time for the user so for example if user selects `Production` it should automatically set all radio buttons to `no` inside div `op`. 
If `Operations` all radio buttons with value `no` should be selected  inside div `prod`.

My function in controller:

```
$scope.division = function(event) {
  if(event.target.id === 'production'){
    $('.op').find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
    $('.prod').find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
  }else{
    $('.prod').find('input:radio').prop('checked', true); 
    $('.op').find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
  }  
};
```

It will select both `yes` and `no` values:
[image]

How can I auto select only radio buttons with `no` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.op').find('input:radio[value="no"]').prop('checked', true);
```

and don't forget to provide the same name to all radio that comes under a group, otherwise they work as checkboxes.

Check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.op').find('input:radio[value="no"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="op">
  <h2>Operations</h2>
    <label><b>Manager: <small id="small">*</small></b></label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" ng-model="formData.mngr" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="group1" ng-model="formData.mngr" value="no">No   

    <label><b>Assistant Manager: <small id="small">*</small></b></label>
    <input type="radio" name="group2" ng-model="formData.asMngr" value="yes">Yes
    <input type="radio" name="group2" ng-model="formData.asMngr" value="no">No  <br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I forgot to put `name` attribute. It works fine with my code too if there is `name`. Thank you